# Align the top of two tables horizontally (side-by-side with minipage)

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, minipage, linguistics, gb4e

I'm using `\minipage` to put two tables side by side. But when the two tables are not of equal length, the shorter of the two is vertically centered with respect to the other. I would like both tables to be aligned horizontally at the top (i.e. so that I could draw an imaginary straight flat line from (1) through (2)).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
        \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
            \begin{exe}
                \ex
                    \begin{tabular}[t]{l l}
                        ich & `I'\\
                        du & `you'\\
                        er & `he'\\
                    \end{tabular}
            \end{exe}
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
            \begin{exe}
                \ex
                    \begin{tabular}[t]{l l}
                        Schiff & `ship'\\
                        Haus & `house'\\
                        Mund & `mouth'\\
                        Auto & `car'\\
                        Buch & `book'\\
                        Stuhl & `chair'\\
                    \end{tabular}
            \end{exe}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Use `[t]` as option for the `minipage` environment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As [Marc van Dongen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/10274/marc-van-dongen) says in a comment, add `[t]` as an option to both `minipage` environments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
            \begin{exe}
                \ex
                    \begin{tabular}[t]{l l}
                        ich & `I'\\
                        du & `you'\\
                        er & `he'\\
                    \end{tabular}
            \end{exe}
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
            \begin{exe}
                \ex
                    \begin{tabular}[t]{l l}
                        Schiff & `ship'\\
                        Haus & `house'\\
                        Mund & `mouth'\\
                        Auto & `car'\\
                        Buch & `book'\\
                        Stuhl & `chair'\\
                    \end{tabular}
            \end{exe}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't add [h] to all tables. You usually don't need them and they make LaTeX layout harder.