# Two tables horizontally aligned at the top

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, formatting

I am struggling to get two tables aligned at the top (horizontal alignment).  I have consulted [Align the top of two tables horizontally (side-by-side with minipage)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101824/align-the-top-of-two-tables-horizontally-side-by-side-with-minipage), [How can I have two tables side by side?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2832/how-can-i-have-two-tables-side-by-side), [Make two figures aligned at top](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101858/make-two-figures-aligned-at-top), [Top-align two parboxes with tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13988/top-align-two-parboxes-with-tables), and many, many more.  I have tried \parbox and \minipage but haven't had any luck.  When I comment out the \minipage code, I get the same thing that I do when the \minipage code is in there.  What's really odd is that I had it aligned using \parbox, except the second table was aligned with the center of the first table.  When I thought I found a fix for it (using \parbox[t]{} ), the tables were then outputted as table 1 (answer box) and then table 2 (scoring box) below it (instead of next to it).  When I removed the [t], nothing changed... the two tables are now stubbornly stacked on top of each other instead of next to each other.  I have been working between \minipage and \parbox as I research new solutions on here, but I am still coming up empty.

(Does the document class have anything to do with it?  Most of the document classes I've found on here are {article} and not {exam}?)

I am relatively new to LaTeX!  Thank you for your patience.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{multirow} % for tables

\pagestyle{headandfoot}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\singlespacing

%to make cells in table have decent spacing
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}

%heading
\begin{flushright}
\begin{tabular}[t]{p{3.8in} r l}
\textbf{class} & \textbf{Name:} & \makebox[2in]{\hrulefill}\\
\textbf{exam} &&\\
\textbf{date} &&
\end{tabular}
\end{flushright}
\rule[1ex]{\textwidth}{.1pt}

%answer box 
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}[t]{ | C{1cm} | R{1.5cm} | }
    \hline
    1. &  \\ 
        & \\ \hline
    2. &  \\ 
        & \\ \hline
    3. &   \\
        & \\ \hline
    4. &   \\
        & \\ \hline
    5. &   \\
        & \\ \hline
    6. &   \\
        & \\ \hline
    7. &   \\ 
        & \\ \hline
\end{tabular} 
\end{minipage}


%scoring box
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}[t]{ | c | R{2cm} | R{1.5cm} | }
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Multiple Choice} & x $(9/7)$ & \\ 
                            &       & \\ \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Free Response} & x 1      & \\ 
                            &       & \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{ c }{} & Your Score out of 18 &      \\ \cline{3-3} 
\end{tabular} \\
\end{minipage}


\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a single `tabularx` in place of two tables. By this, you needn't use `minipage`s to spread the tables a part. The columns of `tabularx` will be the same as your two separate tables plus an `X` column type at the middle to fill the remaining horizontal space. Note also that I used `tabularx` for the first table. This enabled us to use `\hrulefill` directly without `\makebox`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{tabularx}  % for tabularx
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

% to make cells in table have decent spacing
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
% heading
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}p{3.8in} X@{}}
\textbf{class} & \textbf{Name:} \hrulefill \\
\textbf{exam}  &                           \\
\textbf{date}  &                
\end{tabularx}

\addvspace{1em} 
\hrule height .1pt 
\addvspace{1em}

% answer box 
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|C{1cm}|R{1.5cm}| X |c|R{2cm}|R{1.5cm}|}
    \cline{1-2}\cline{4-6}
    1. &  &  & Multiple Choice & ${}\times(9/7)$ & \\ \cline{1-2}\cline{4-6} 
    2. &  &  & Free Response   & ${}\times1$     & \\ \cline{1-2}\cline{4-6}
    3. &  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{r|}{Your Score out of 18} & \\ \cline{1-2}\cline{6-6}
    4. &   \\ \cline{1-2}
    5. &   \\ \cline{1-2}
    6. &   \\ \cline{1-2}
    7. &   \\ \cline{1-2}  
\end{tabularx} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Yet another simpler option is to use two `tabular`s with the `[t]` alignment option as follows (with the same result as above):

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{|C{1cm}|R{1.5cm}|}
    \hline
    1. &  \\ \hline
    2. &  \\ \hline
    3. &  \\ \hline
    4. &  \\ \hline
    5. &  \\ \hline
    6. &  \\ \hline
    7. &  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|R{2cm}|R{1.5cm}|}
   \hline
   Multiple Choice & ${}\times(9/7)$ & \\ \hline
   Free Response   & ${}\times1$     & \\ \hline
   \multicolumn{2}{r|}{Your Score out of 18} & \\ \cline{3-3}
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: The first method worked for me!  Thank you.  I will learn more about the tabularx package now since that was super simple.  Additionally, the two tabular methods with [t] did NOT work for me... for some reason.  And at this point in my LaTeX education, I am only mildly interested in why it didn't work.  However, I am interested in knowing if there is a way to get "Your score out of 18" to wrap so that it isn't multicolumn?  This is a curiosity, not something I need for this particular document I'm working on.  Thank you!!

Comment: @Jenni -- As to why the second solution didn't work, we need a complete MWE showing the wrong output you mention to fix it for you. To wrap "Your score out of 18" you may change the third row to `3. &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \vbox to .6cm {Your Score out of 18} & \\ \cline{1-2}\cline{6-6}`. I'm too lazy now to explain, but you can understand what this command does with some search.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

[image]

you were very close to this ... i only change `minipage` option from `b` to `t` and between tables add `hfill` and delete empty line between `minipage`s:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{multirow} % for tables

\pagestyle{headandfoot}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
%\singlespacing

%to make cells in table have decent spacing
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}

%heading
\begin{flushright}
\begin{tabular}[t]{p{3.8in} r l}
\textbf{class} & \textbf{Name:} & \makebox[2in]{\hrulefill}\\
\textbf{exam}  &&\\
\textbf{date}  &&
\end{tabular}
\end{flushright}
\rule[1ex]{\textwidth}{.1pt}
%answer box

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}[t]{ | C{1cm} | R{1.5cm} | }
    \hline
    1. &  \\
        & \\ \hline
    2. &  \\
        & \\ \hline
    3. &   \\
        & \\ \hline
    4. &   \\
        & \\ \hline
    5. &   \\
        & \\ \hline
    6. &   \\
        & \\ \hline
    7. &   \\
        & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
%scoring box
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}[t]{ | c | R{2cm} | R{1.5cm} | }
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Multiple Choice} & x $(9/7)$ & \\
                            &       & \\ \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Free Response} & x 1      & \\
                            &       & \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{ c }{} & Your Score out of 18 &      \\ \cline{3-3}
\end{tabular} \\
\end{minipage}


\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your encouragement!  This solution did not work for me, however :(  I had tried this and a few other small tweaks and it just wasn't coming together.  I'm not sure why but my output still had the two tables stacked one on top of the other.  Odd.

Comment: @jeni, my answer gives equal result as of *aboammar*, what then not work to you? you should be more specific and clear what you like to have. sorry.